# Pure-CSS slide-in element interacting oddly with <audio> element

Tags: html, css

I have a page on which the user can click a **link** and a panel slides in **from the right to cover half of the page**. It only uses `CSS`, `no JS`, and it works fine usually.

However, the main part of the page has an `<audio>` element and as soon as I add a `URL` to it, the panel opening behavior goes strange - the panel does slide in, but the main page contents jump offscreen and slide in from the left. Here's a minimal example.

[JS Fiddle available here](https://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/8vschu49/6/)

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s;
}

#panel:target {
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<audio class="player" controls>
  <!-- Remove the URL below and things work as expected: -->
  <source src="http://stream-relay-geo.ntslive.net/stream" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>

<a href="#panel">Open panel</a>

<div id="panel">
  <a href="#top">Close panel</a>
</div>
```

I can't figure out (a) why the presence of the URL causes this to happen, or (b) how to stop it.

Comment: I'm not sure i'm seeing what you're describing correctly but the audio tag doesn't seem to be the problem, The page jumps a tiny bit, it's small but visible, And it happens regardless of the whole `<audio>` element

Comment: @ZohirSalak Sorry, I should have said I was using Safari on Mac. I can see that in Firefox it works as expected, with the URL in the `<audio>` element. Strange Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from your targeted element being transitioned in off screen. When you click on the anchor, the `#panel` element is in focus/selected, and the browser will attempt to move the viewport in a way such that the element remains visible in the viewport. Since your element is rendered outside the viewport but slides in after, this causes the browser to keep adjusting its horizontal scroll position to keep it in view.

A possible workaround is to simply wrap the contents of `#panel` in an inner `<div>` element, and position that inner div element absolutely. In this case, `#panel` always remains on screen in a way:

```css
#panel .inner {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s;
}

#panel:target .inner {
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<audio class="player" controls>
      <!-- Remove the URL below and things work as expected: -->
      <source src="http://stream-relay-geo.ntslive.net/stream" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

<a href="#panel">Open panel</a>

<div id="panel">
  <div class="inner">
    <a href="#top">Close panel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing Terry, thank you! I'm baffled as to why (in Safari on Mac at least, which I forgot to mention) adding a URL to the audio element caused this. But your solution works, whatever the cause was.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the transition-delay in css-rule. Whether the audio is loaded or not, if you try to open the side bar while it is getting closed, it will create the issue..

To fix that just lower the transition-delay value and it should work fine..

```
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 1s ease 0.1s;
}

#panel:target {
  background: #ccc;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 1s ease 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. Yes, that seems to help, although I get some odd movements showing (in Safari).